# maven-resources-plugin + profiles

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, maven-war-plugin, maven-profiles, maven-resources-plugin

I am moving an existing project (legacy) to maven. It has the following structure:

```
ParentProject
 - EARModule
   - src
   - target
   - pom.xml (ear)
 - WARModule
   - src
     - main
       - java
         - (java packages and classes)
       - resources
         - dev
           - index.jsp
         - prod
           - index.jsp
       - webapp
         - views
           - index.jsp (original)
         - WEB-INF
   - target
   - pom.xml (war)
 - pom.xml (parent)
```

I intend to have two different profiles: production and development. In production profile, /WARModule/src/main/resources/**prod**/index.jsp should be assembled into views/ war directory. In development profile, /WARModule/src/main/resources/**dev**/index.jsp should be copied into views/ war directory.

For that, I am trying to make use of the maven-resources-plugin, which I am configuring in war pom.xml.

```
<properties>
    <prodResourcesDir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/prod</prodResourcesDir>
    <devResourcesDir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/dev</devResourcesDir>
    <viewsDir>${basedir}/target/WARModule/views</viewsDir>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy_development_index.jsp</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${viewsDir}</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${devResourcesDir}</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>index.jsp</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy_production_index.jsp</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${viewsDir}</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${prodResourcesDir}</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>index.jsp</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

As you can see above, I am creating two profiles (production and development) and configuring the resources plugin under each of them.

When I run mvn install -P any_of_the_profiles, index.jsp is not copied to the specified destination. Instead, I get the original version. Can anyone help me sort this out?

Below the log trace:

```
$ mvn -P production install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] ParentProject
[INFO] WebModule Maven Webapp
[INFO] EARModule
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ParentProject 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ParentProject ---
[INFO] Installing D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\pom.xml to C:\Users\a048148\.m2\repository\my\org\ParentProject\0.0.2-SNAPSHOT\ParentProject-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WebModule Maven Webapp 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ WebModule ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 10 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ WebModule ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compilation messages...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ WebModule ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\WebModule\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WebModule ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ WebModule ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:copy-resources (copy_index.jsp) @ WebModule ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ WebModule ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [WebModule] in [D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\WebModule\target\WebModule]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\WebModule\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [3122 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\WebModule\target\WebModule.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ WebModule ---
[INFO] Installing D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\WebModule\target\WebModule.war to C:\Users\a048148\.m2\repository\my\org\WebModule\0.0.2-SNAPSHOT\WebModule-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\WebModule\pom.xml to C:\Users\a048148\.m2\repository\my\org\WebModule\0.0.2-SNAPSHOT\WebModule-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building EARModule 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @ EARModule ---
[INFO] Generating application.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ EARModule ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.8:ear (default-ear) @ EARModule ---
[INFO] Copying artifact [war:com.bbh:WebModule:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] to [WebModule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
[INFO] Could not find manifest file: D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\EARModule\target\ParentProject\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF - Generating one
[INFO] Building jar: D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\EARModule\target\ParentProject.ear
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ EARModule ---
[INFO] Installing D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\EARModule\target\ParentProject.ear to C:\Users\a048148\.m2\repository\my\org\EARModule\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\EARModule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear
[INFO] Installing D:\workspace\mvn_projects\ParentProject\EARModule\pom.xml to C:\Users\a048148\.m2\repository\my\org\EARModule\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\EARModule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] ParentProject .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.229 s]
[INFO] WebModule Maven Webapp ................................ SUCCESS [ 19.470 s]
[INFO] EARModule ............................................. SUCCESS [  3.049 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.892 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-12T15:18:14+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that maven-resources-plugin works just fine for **resources**, not **web resources** (JSP).

So I switched my approach to the [maven-war-plugin filtering feature](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) and specifying the destination path. Thus, the profiles section in my web pom.xml ended up like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${devResourcesDir}</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <targetPath>views</targetPath> <!-- target/WebModule/ subdirectory -->
                                <include>index.jsp</include>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${prodResourcesDir}</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <targetPath>views</targetPath> <!-- target/WebModule/ subdirectory -->
                                <include>index.jsp</include>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This tells maven-war-plugin to move *index.jsp* from the specified resources directory to the *target/WebModule/views* directory. It is all done by the war plugin just before packaging the war, so there is no need to specify the life cycle phase.